# Do I have to use a fixed size to display scrollbar for HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I think it is odd that you can't enable scrollbars for a table, a div or a page without setting the element to a fixed width or a fixed height. Why can't it be done without the fixed width? I tried `overflow: auto` but that doesn't work.

I'm just trying to enable a scrollbar and then CSS forces me to do what I think is unnecessary. Why doesn't it work?

**Update**

In this case it was sufficient to just do this:

```
body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell whether content is flowing over the container if you don't know the size of the container :)

Comment: @JessedeBruijne But the sizes should be known because the window is smaller than the container.

Comment: Then the window will be overflowing, not the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **yes, you need a fixed size**

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

In order to tell if content is overflowing a container, you must specify a size of the container. Otherwise, there is no way of telling when content is overflowing a container.

If you need a scrollbar at all times, use `overflow: scroll`, otherwise, specify a height (or a max-height).

Comment: `overflow: scroll !important;` doesn't give me a vertical scrollbar, only a horizontal. Why?

Comment: it probably defaults to horizontal, if you want a vertical scrollbar use `overflow-x: scroll`

Answer (score 2):

yes !
Note: The overflow property only works for block elements with a specified height.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp